# I want to turn the first sheet of every excel workbook into their own individual pdfs

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code below, but want to change it to only save the first sheet listed (left most) as a pdf, and repeat/iterate over an entire folder of .xlsx spreadsheets.

```
Dim sFile       As String
Dim sPath       As String
Dim wks         As Worksheet

With ActiveWorkbook
    sPath = .Path & "\"
    For Each wks In .Worksheets
            sFile = wks.Name & ".pdf"
            wks.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                    Filename:=sPath & sFile, _
                                    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                    IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
                                    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                    OpenAfterPublish:=False
    Next wks
End With
End Sub
```

I'm very new to writing macros / code of any sort, so thank you for your help!

Comment: Instead of looping through all worksheets `For Each wks In .Worksheets` just export the first one `.Worksheets(1).ExportAsFixedFormat …` • It is very unclear what exactly you tried and what your issue is.

Comment: Also, `sFile = .Worksheets(1).Name & ".pdf"`.

Comment: @BigBen Well yes, didn't see that, but turning worksheet names into filenames is not recommended. If you need to do that you need to make sure to strip off not allowed characters from the worksheet name, otherwise you easily run into errors. `/ \ : * ? " < > |` are not allowed in file names but `" < > |` are allowed in worksheet names.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ This code currently 'successfully' produces a pdf for every sheet in one workbook.  Instead of this, I would like it to produce a unique pdf for the first sheet in every workbook in a specified folder. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: you should loop the folder that contains excel files, and use this working code inside loop. of course if you need only first sheet what PEH sugggested is practical solution. when looping in folder you can use FileSystemObject of VBA.

Comment: Have a look here for how to loop through workbooks in a folder: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60887390/looping-through-workbooks-in-a-folder then do what was suggested in the comments above.